# Cómo deshabilitar en Wordpress la confirmación por e-mail cuando el usuario cambia su correo electrónico

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un sitio con Wordpress y Buddypress instalado. La versión de Wordpress es la 5.2.1. y Buddypress está actualizado también.

El sitio es una Intranet (no una red social) en la que la carga de usuarios la realizo a través de un CSV. De cada uno incluyo su nombre, contraseña (la misma que el nombre) y una dirección de correo electrónico ficticia porque desconozco las direcciones personales de cada usuario (son casi 100). Cada usuario debe entrar y cambiar la contraseña y su dirección de correo electrónico.

El problema es que, cuando intentan cambiar esta dirección de correo electrónico, aparece un mensaje en el que avisa que para confirmar el cambio debes revisar la dirección de correo electrónico antigua (que es inventada). Por tanto nadie puede cambiar la dirección porque, lógicamente, no tienen acceso a esas cuentas de correo. Aquí podéis ver una captura de lo que sale: https://prnt.sc/o0veqp

Me gustaría deshabilitar o saltar ese paso de manera que el usuario pueda meter el correo que quiera sin necesidad de confirmación por su parte. ¿Es posible?

He probado a añadir este código en functions.php pero no funciona:

```
add_filter( 'wcfm_is_allow_email_verification', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Según veo podrías hacerlo añadiendo esto a tu archivo functions.php de tu child theme , o usando el plugin [Code Snippets](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/)

```
remove_action('personal_options_update', 'send_confirmation_on_profile_email');
```

Fuente:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?q=send_confirmation_on_profile_email&unscoped_q=send_confirmation_on_profile_email

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/300141)